# How to securely publish same npm package by several different people?

Tags: javascript, npm, open-source

There is an open source project. Multiple people are working on it. Multiple people need to publish it to the NPM registry.

How to securely publish a single project by multiple people?

Obviously, the owner of the package do not want to give his login/password to other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the npm docs:

> npm owner add <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
>
> npm owner rm <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
>
> npm owner ls [<@scope>/]<pkg>

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/owner